# Chrome Google Cast Plugin Integration With VideoJS

Tags: google-chrome, google-cast, chromecast

I'm trying to integrate the Google Cast plugin for Chrome with VideoJS. I started off by looking into [this plugin](https://github.com/benjipott/video.js-chromeCast) but it only provides a visual button and some code that doesn't appear to connect with the Google Cast plugin. I have no problem writing the backend code to link videoJS and the Google Cast plugin together. What I am having a hard time figuring out though is how to handle interaction once the video is loaded. Sites like youtube use the player's controls to play, pause, seek, etc which will obviously try to do those same things on the video player itself. I'm trying to figure out a way to use the videoJS interface but not have it actually do anything with the local player. I could copy the interface but then I'd have to handle everything manually and would prefer to avoid this if possible. Does anyone have any better ideas on how to deal with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The video.js-chromecast plugin does provide hooks with Chrome sender SDK and if it's done right, it should be able to launch/open session and load media.

To control media with play/pause/resume, you'd have to override calls to local playback in video.js.  This project https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome provides UX reference sample and it handles transition between cast mode and local playback.

Comment: I guess I should of clarified a bit. The plugin does have some hooks, however they are for the beta API which has now changed since its release. As you say, you still have the issues with overriding local playback as well which is what my question was really regarding. I ended up duplicating the player and having to manually link everything up. Not fun but it works. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @brian-f-leighty Hey hey, do you happen to have any code samples of your "linking up" of the two?  I'd love to work with you on building something that ties them seamlessly together.  Like a plugin that is used when `cast` is available or whatever.

Comment: @JoshuaF.Rountree I haven't worked on in several years. I believe there are some existing plugins now that handle this but I honestly haven't looked into them at all. I believe the code I wrote is still in use here http://defensetv.com/ although I believe they are planning to change it over sometime soon in the future so if you're interested I'd download the files right away.